# 3 or 4 parameter x86 assembly in AT&T syntax

Tags: assembly, syntax, x86, x86-64, gnu-assembler

Simple question. I doubt this will receive much attention, but how do I do 3 or 4 parameter operations in x86-64 assembly in AT&T (gAS) syntax? It's known to any x86 programmer using gAS that the arguments are *switched*, for example:

```
xor   eax,  ebx ; Intel (xASM)
xorl %ebx, %eax ; AT&T (gAS)
```

But how would I do, say:

```
blendpd xmm0, xmm1, 5
```

What I mean is, how are the instructions written? I get that there would be `%xmm0` and such (still prefixes on parameters), but how are they ordered and what suffix do I add at the end of the instruction (the `l` in `movl` for 32-bit)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AT&T equivalent would be where the order of operands is reversed:

```
blendpd $5, %xmm1, %xmm0
```

If you are unsure you can always compile with Intel syntax then disassemble to AT&T.

Comment: Plus, where's the suffix on the instruction?

Comment: The suffix is not necessary since the size can be inferred from the destination. You can disassemble to AT&T syntax with `objdump -Dslx BINARY`. Or look at the assembly stage with `gcc -S` (not sure what compiler you are using).

Comment: See [Instruction Naming](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMnemonics.html).